# Spring database switching working for all users, but not per user

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my spring project i am using different databases for different users. To support that, I configured AbstractRoutingDataSource bean.

Here is my code:

```
 @Primary
 @Bean(name="routingDatasource")
 public AbstractRoutingDataSource routingDatasource()
 {
     Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources=new HashMap<Object, Object>();

     targetDataSources.put(Db.comp1,dataSourceComp1());
     targetDataSources.put(Db.comp2,dataSourceComp2());

     AbstractRoutingDataSource dataSrc=new AbstractRoutingDataSource() {

        @Override
        protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {

            return DataBaseRouteFixer.getKey();
        }
    };

    dataSrc.setDefaultTargetDataSource(dataSourceComp2());
    dataSrc.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
    System.out.println("abstract routing data source created");
    return dataSrc;
 }
```

Db is an enum, in Db i defined bunch of user keys there.

database Route fixer:

```
@Component
public class DataBaseRouteFixer {

private static final ThreadLocal<Db> route=new ThreadLocal<Db>();

public static Db getKey() {
    return route.get();
}
public static void setKey(Db key) {
      route.set(key);
}
```

Switching code for databases in controller:

```
DataBaseRouteFixer.setKey(Db.comp1);
```

It's working, but when I switch the database the same change affects other users as well. I want it to switch different databases per user, how can I do that?

Comment: In Spring by default scope of every object in singleton. So every request coming to your server have same object. If you changed that object every request will now use that new object.

Comment: agreed any examples or suggestions?

Comment: If you want to use different database for every request you can make bean of scope prototype but this is too bad. Is their any option you can divide your users in some category??

Comment: If you can divide them in some category then you can create one datasource object for every database you have. Now define two dao layer object one for each database. Now depending on user category whose request is coming you can use corresponding dao layer object.

Comment: two dao layer is not possible here, that is equal to multiple project files

Comment: How are you managing your transactions? Is your change affecting both data sources or only one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as i am concerned, it is hard to implement abstract data source routing among multiple users. I need to use hibernate to solve this problem. it is multi-tenancy that what i am actually looking for.

[i found this article helpful](https://dzone.com/articles/multi-tenancy-using-jpa-spring-and-hibernate-part)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create proxy DataSource which can delegate all the calls to proper real DataSource taken from targetDataSources map based on thread local variable.

```
public class ProxyDataSource implements DataSource {
...
    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return getRealDataSource().getConnection();
    }
...
}
```

and use the Proxy where you need data source.

Answer (score 0):

OP needs to have a different database for each user or set of users.

You can use spring session beans for beans which are stateful and their state differs per user. These can be for example preferences of currently logged in user.

Default scope of bean in spring is singleton and it is no different in Web Application context.